# How to give one user full access to MongoDB right after install?

Tags: mongodb, database-security

I just installed MongoDB 4.4 on Ubuntu 20.04. Now, I want one user with a password to have full access (create database, write to it, delete it, etc.) over TCP port 27017. How can I do this?

Comment: First, you need to enable the security on the database server. Basic concepts are the Authentication and Authorization - these will allow to create users with id/password _and_ the access control (specify what the users can do and not)

Answer (score 0):

First, I changed `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

Then, I created a new user:

```
$ mongo
use admin
db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"foo",roles:[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}]})
```

Then, added these lines to `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Then, restarted it:

```
$ sudo service mongod restart
```

Finally, I was able to connect to it both from the server and remotely (after adding TCP port 27017 to the list of inbound rules of my AWS EC2 security group):

```
$ mongo localhost:27017 -u admin -p foo
```